# How to spawn a celery task from previous celery task?

Tags: python, asynchronous, redis, celery, botframework

I maybe using celery incorrectly. But the chatbot I am developing requires celery with redis for async tasks. This is the framework I am using: http://microsoftbotframework.readthedocs.io/en/latest/asynctasks/.

My particular use case currently requires me to run a celery task **forever** and wait for some arbitrary amount of time in between, which ranges from 30 minutes to  3 days. Something like this

```
@celery.task
def myAsyncMethod():
    while true:
        timeToWait = getTimeToNextAlarm()
        sleep(timeToWait)
        sendOutMessages()
```

Basically, I have an async process which never exits. I am pretty sure shouldn't be using celery like this. **So my question is, how do I create a celery task which processes the first task, spawns a task and submits it to celery queue and exits.** Basically, something like this:

```
@celery.task
def myImprovedTask():
    timeToWait = getTimeToNextAlarm()
    sleep(timeToWait)
    sendOutMessages()
    myImprovedTask().delay()    # recursive call to async method for next event
```

Not necessarily recursive or even like this, but something which is the way celery originally is intended to be used (for short lived tasks I believe?)

Tl;dr: How do I create a celery task from within another task and make the original task exit?

Do tell if I should explain it further. Thanks.

Comment: If you want to run a task periodically, then it's here : http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/userguide/periodic-tasks.html

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to run another task from your initial task, just call it as you would usually do with [`Task.delay()`](http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/reference/celery.app.task.html#celery.app.task.Task.delay), or [`Task.apply_async()`](http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/reference/celery.app.task.html#celery.app.task.Task.apply_async):

```
@celery.task
def myImprovedTask():
    timeToWait = getTimeToNextAlarm()
    sleep(timeToWait)
    sendOutMessages()
    myImprovedTask.delay()
```

It doesn't matter if you call the same task again. It gets enqueued with `delay()`, your original task returns, and then the next task in queue gets run.

---

All this is under an assumption *you are actually calling your Celery tasks asynchronously*. Sometimes that's not a case, a common culprit being the [`task-always-eager`](http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/userguide/configuration.html#task-always-eager) config option. By default it's disabled, **but** (from the [docs](http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/userguide/configuration.html#task-always-eager)):

> If **`task_always_eager`** is `True`, **all tasks will be executed locally by blocking until the task returns**. `apply_async()` and `Task.delay()` will return an `EagerResult` instance, that emulates the API and behavior of `AsyncResult`, except the result is already evaluated.
>
> That is, tasks will be executed locally **instead of being sent to the queue.**

So, be sure your Celery config includes:

```
task_always_eager = False
```

Comment: I did try this. Actually I should I have mentioned. I used delay() itself. But after a while it run out of workers and no tasks were being executed.

Comment: Are you sure your tasks are asynchronous? After queuing, `delay()` should return and the previous task will finish.

Comment: let me try this out real quick and will get back to you.

Comment: If your tasks are ["eager"](http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/userguide/configuration.html#task-always-eager), they are run locally and blocking until finished.

Comment: I haven't explicity set them to the eager setting, but that seems to be the case. Because, when I did `        myImprovedTask.delay()
        logging.info('ending first event async task. bye..')` . And in my pycharm debugger placed a debug point at the start of the method. On calling myImprovedTask.delay(), it directly went inside that method to that debug point. The logging message was not printed on console.

Comment: Try setting `task_always_eager = False` in your config and running the code *outside of the debugger*.

Comment: it worked. Could you put some of the things in these comments to your answer? That way I could accept this as the answer. The comments helped, especially the `task_always_eager=false` settings. Thanks.

Comment: Great, I'm glad that was the problem and you made it work. I've updated the answer.

Comment: Could you possibly take a look at this also? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45356059/force-stop-celery-workers-running-as-a-systemd-service

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/150338/discussion-between-dhruv-sangvikar-and-randomir).

Answer (score 0):

> If the task isn’t registered in the current process you can use
>   send_task() to call the task by name instead

as defined in the docs here http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/reference/celery.html#celery.Celery.send_task

```
app.send_task('task_name')
```

Doing it this way, you have to explicitly name the tasks like:

```
@celery.task(name="myImprovedTask")
def myImprovedTask():
```

And then you are able to call it with:

```
app.send_task('myImprovedTask')
```

If you do not like this way (or you have the file in the same file), you can also call it with [apply_async](http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/reference/celery.app.task.html#celery.app.task.Task.apply_async) or [delay](http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/reference/celery.app.task.html#celery.app.task.Task.delay) like:

```
myImprovedTask.delay()
myImprovedTask.apply_async()
```

Comment: Hey thanks for the suggestion. But on calling myImprovedTask.delay() it directly goes inside the next task without exiting the first task.